# Matplotlib title location in matplotlibrc config

Tags: python, matplotlib

The `matplotlibrc` config file has the option to set various `title` settings:

```
axes.titlesize      : medium   # fontsize of the axes title
axes.titlepad       : 6.0     # pad between axes and title in points
```

Is there an option to put the title by default on the left, as can manually be done with:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
pl.figure()
pl.title('Title....', loc='left')
```

For e.g. the `legend` there is an option:

```
legend.loc           : best
```

But I can't find anything similar for the title location.

Comment: Correct, there is no such option present. If you want to inform the matplotlib team about your wish to have such an option, you may use the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).